# Wrong value of property after assignment - C#

Tags: c#, .net

I stumbled upon this problem where I assign a value to the property CurrentHp on my Character class and the value is incorrect and does not match right handside.

The Character class inherits from GameEntity and the code for both classes looks like this:

GameEntity

```
public abstract class GameEntity
{
    public int BaseDmgMin { get; set; }
    public int BaseDmgMax { get; set; }
    public virtual int CurrentHp { get; set; }
    public int MaxHp { get; set; }

    public bool IsDead()
    {
        if (CurrentHp < 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public abstract int TakeDamage(int damage);
    public abstract int Attack();
}
```

Character

```
public class Character : GameEntity
{
    public Character(String CharacterName, int Exp, int Gold) : this()
   {
        this.CharacterName = CharacterName;
        this.Exp = Exp;
        this.Gold = Gold;

    }

    public Character(){
        Inventory = new Inventory();
    }

    public Guid CharacterID { get; set; }
    public string CharacterName { get; set; }
    public int Exp { get; set; }
    public int Gold { get; set; }
    public Weapon Weapon { get; set; }
    public Shield Shield { get; set; }
    public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastHealthUpdate { get; set; }
    public bool InFight { get; set; }
    public override int CurrentHp
    {
        get
        {
            if (!InFight)
            {
                var timeHealth = TimeHealth();
                if (timeHealth > 0)
                {
                    LastHealthUpdate = DateTime.Now;
                    base.CurrentHp = (base.CurrentHp + timeHealth) > MaxHp ? MaxHp : base.CurrentHp + timeHealth;
                } 
            }

            return base.CurrentHp;
        }
        set{ base.CurrentHp = value; }
    }

    public void UpdateHealth()
    {
       var a = CurrentHp;
    }

    public override int Attack()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int hitDamage = r.Next(BaseDmgMin, BaseDmgMax);
        if (Weapon != null)
            hitDamage += Weapon.Damage;

        return hitDamage;
    }

    public int TimeHealth()
    {
        var diffMilli = DateTime.Now - LastHealthUpdate;
        var intervals = (int)diffMilli.TotalMinutes / 5;
        return intervals;
    }

    public int GoldLoss()
    {
        int gold = Gold;
        Random r = new Random();
        int multiplier = r.Next(30, 50);
        gold = (gold * multiplier) / 100;
        Gold -= gold;

        return gold;
    }

    public int ExpLoss()
    {
        var expLoss = Convert.ToInt32(Exp * 0.9);
        Exp -= expLoss;
        return expLoss;
    }

    public void GoldGain(int gold) {
        this.Gold += gold;
    }

    public void ExpGain(int exp) {
        this.Exp += exp;
    }

    public override int TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        if (Shield != null)
            damage = (damage - Shield.Armor > 0) ? damage - Shield.Armor : 0;

        CurrentHp = (CurrentHp - damage > 0) ? CurrentHp - damage : 0;
        return damage;
    }


}
```

When I step through the code I see the following:

1: CurrentHp has the value 0 but should have the value 25.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/faMYY.jpg

2: CurrentHp now has the value 100 without any more assignments to CurrentHp being executed.
http://imgur.com/KvS3WCu

What have I missed or what am I doing wrong? 
I appreciate all the help I can get :)

Comment: You should create a private field to store the actual value of `CurrentHp` and work with it

Comment: Does it happen in the same block, for the same character ? If so, is it possible your DataRow gets changed during the Character "mapping", like some kind of async action ?

Comment: random guess, but I bet it has somthing to do with the integer division you have on `var intervals = (int)diffMilli.TotalMinutes / 5;`in TimeHealth

Comment: @Mickael V. Yes, it happens for the same character. I'm not making any async calls of what I know.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain I didn't think that mattered since it is part of the get and not the set

Comment: @Vsevolod Goloviznin I tried doing what you suggested in the GameEntity class but I don't think it is that cause is still get the same problem

Comment: I checked the DataRow object when stepping through the code and found that the values stay the same through out the block. So the DataRow object does not change.

Comment: Make the private field in the `Character` class and everything should work

Comment: @Vsevolod Goloviznin Okey, tried that as well and it didn't work. Why do you think that is the problem?  Am I using the abstract class together with Properties in the wrong way? If I add a private field to the Character class it also feels like I'm ignoring the fact that I already inherit that logic from GameEntity.

Comment: Avoid such logic in your properties! You should have the logic performed in proper methods.

Comment: You are changing a value in the get?  Don't do that.

Comment: @Yorye Nathan Ok, moved the logic to a method which made everything work again! I'm curious why this happend though, what made it behave like it did? What type of logic is more appropriate in properties?

Thanks a bunch for the help!

Comment: No logic is appropriate in properties. The most you want to find yourself doing is informing that the property has been changed, and whatever code that cares about it will listen to this event and re-read the value to update accordingly.